# Create a history event

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a spring + JPA project.

I would like to create events entries and persist them in a table, for example:

a) Entity "User" with id 4 was changed: in property named "userName" oldValue: "john" newValue: "johnnie"

b) A new Customer email was recieved, therfore we created a new Ticket for this email and the assignee for this email is user named: "Goku"

My question is:

What is the best practice for creating such mechanism? currently I have 2 ideas which are not suffice:

1) I can insert the following code on every place in the code i would like to create history event:

```
historyManager.createEvent(String event string,String newValue, String oldValue, Date date);
```

Although this solution works, it is extremely ugly and not generic at all.

2) Use Hibernate Envers, this library actually logs every entity change in my project with simple annotation : "@Audited"
Problem is that this solution impacts preformance and to be honest not very appealing to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the Envers approach. If performance really becomes a problem, then you can solve it by different ways. For instance, by partitioning your data, by using special "engines" (in case of MySQL), store in a different schema/catalog, ... And you get it almost for "free", specially comparing to the option of doing everything by yourself.

Comment: I really want to avoid this envers library

Comment: Any specific reason to avoid it? Performance is not really an issue, specially if you have not measured the impacts yet ;-)

Comment: 1) Our CTO used it before and hated everything about it.  2) If one does not use hibernate what would he do?

Comment: Point 1 is not really objective, and point 2 is only valid if you don't plan to use JPA (or Hibernate). But then, I don't understand why you mentioned Envers as an option in your question, the only concrete negative side being "performance" (which is not an issue, IMO).